# java.sql.sqlexception: cannot get a connection, pool error timeout waiting for idle object.

Tags: java

i am getting java.sql.sqlexception: cannot get a connection, pool error timeout waiting for idle object.  error from below code. Please, help me to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

I am using below code in middleware for some enterprise application.

```
package ConnectionClass;

import PWConnectionClass.PlatwareConnectionDetail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

public class ConnectionPOOL
{
  private static BasicDataSource ds = null;

  static
  {
    try {
      if (PlatwareConnectionDetail.PlatwareDbType.equalsIgnoreCase("MySql")) {
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUsername(PlatwareConnectionDetail.USERID);

        ds.setPassword(PlatwareConnectionDetail.PASSWORD);
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + PlatwareConnectionDetail.IP + ":" + PlatwareConnectionDetail.PORT + "/" + PlatwareConnectionDetail.DB_OR_ServiceNameForOracle);
        ds.setMaxActive(1000);
        ds.setMaxIdle(100);
        ds.setMaxWait(30000);
      }
      if (PlatwareConnectionDetail.PlatwareDbType.equalsIgnoreCase("Oracle")) {

        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUsername(PlatwareConnectionDetail.USERID);
        ds.setPassword(PlatwareConnectionDetail.PASSWORD);
        if(PlatwareConnectionDetail.IS_LOAD_BALANCE.length()>0&&(PlatwareConnectionDetail.IS_LOAD_BALANCE.equalsIgnoreCase("ON") ||PlatwareConnectionDetail.IS_LOAD_BALANCE.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")))
        {
            String loadBalanceString=PlatwareConnectionDetail.LOAD_BALANCER_STRING;
            String  URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+loadBalanceString;      
//        System.out.println(URL);
        ds.setUrl(URL);
        }
        else
        {
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + PlatwareConnectionDetail.IP + ":" + PlatwareConnectionDetail.PORT + ":" + PlatwareConnectionDetail.DB_OR_ServiceNameForOracle);   
        }
        ds.setMaxActive(1000);
        ds.setMaxIdle(100);
        ds.setMaxWait(30000);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      e.getMessage();
    }
  }

  public static Connection getConnection()
    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
  {

      if(ds==null)
        {
            Connection con=null;
            if(PlatwareConnectionDetail.PlatwareDbType.equalsIgnoreCase("MYSQL"))
            {
            con=MySqlConnection.getConnection(PlatwareConnectionDetail.IP, PlatwareConnectionDetail.PORT, PlatwareConnectionDetail.DB_OR_ServiceNameForOracle, PlatwareConnectionDetail.USERID, PlatwareConnectionDetail.PASSWORD);
            }
            else
            {
            con=OracleConnection.getConnection(PlatwareConnectionDetail.IP, PlatwareConnectionDetail.PORT, PlatwareConnectionDetail.DB_OR_ServiceNameForOracle,PlatwareConnectionDetail. USERID,PlatwareConnectionDetail. PASSWORD, "OFF", "0");
            }
            return con;
        }
        else
        {
            return ds.getConnection();      
        }

  }

  public static void closeConnection(Connection con) {
    try {
      if ((con != null) && (!con.isClosed()))
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void closeStmt(Statement statement)
  {
    try {
      if (statement != null)
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public static void closeRS(ResultSet resultSet)
  {
    try {
      if (resultSet != null)
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - please add the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: And make sure it's the COMPLETE stack trace, including all "Caused By" sections. The error probably results from a connection leak taking up all available connections, and that will be a bug in the code the uses your connection pool.

Comment: i didnt get complete stack trace, i get this from some log files.Please help me to find bug in my code.